# numpy ndarray advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I have ndarray of 3 dimension.
How do I select index 0 and 1 from first axis while selecting index 0 and 3 from second axis and index 1 from third axis?

I tried to use index [(0,1), (1, 3), 1], which produces a result completely different than what I thought it would produce.

So two questions here. 
What does [(0,1), (1, 3), 1] do?
And how to correctly create an index that solve my original question.

```
a = np.arange(30).reshape(3, 5, 2)
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17],
        [18, 19]],

       [[20, 21],
        [22, 23],
        [24, 25],
        [26, 27],
        [28, 29]]])

a[0, (1, 3), 1]  # produces array([3, 7])
a[(0,1), (1, 3), 1] # produces array([ 3, 17])
```

```

Comment: ...and what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you index the way you're doing it, NumPy doesn't interpret it as selecting those indices of each dimension. Instead, NumPy broadcasts the arguments against each other:

```
a[(0,1), (1, 3), 1] -> a[array([0, 1]), array([1, 3]), array([1, 1])]
```

and then creates a result array where `a[i, j, k][x] == a[i[x], j[x], k[x]]`.

To get the behavior you're looking for, you need to reshape the arguments you're passing, so that broadcasting them against each other produces an array of shape `(2, 2)` instead of shape `(2,)`. This means the first argument needs shape `(2, 1)`, the second argument needs to have shape `(1, 2)` or `(2,)`, and the third argument's shape is fine. [`numpy.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) can make this easier, but it doesn't support scalar arguments. `a[np.ix_([0, 1], [1, 3], [1])]` does what you would have expected `a[[0, 1], [1, 3], [1]]` to do, but to get the shape you would have expected from `a[[0, 1], [1, 3], 1]`, your options are messier:

```
>>> a[np.ix_([0, 1], [1, 3], [1])]
array([[[ 3],
        [ 7]],

       [[13],
        [17]]])
>>> a[np.ix_([0, 1], [1, 3]) + (1,)]
array([[ 3,  7],
       [13, 17]])
>>> a[np.ix_([0, 1], [1, 3], [1])][:, :, 0]
array([[ 3,  7],
       [13, 17]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains. I just read up about the numpy broadcasting. ix_ function looks good and seems to satisfies what I need.