# irregular slicing/copying in numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, copy, scipy, slice

Suppose I have an array with 10 elements, e.g. `a=np.arange(10)`. If I want to create another array with the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th, 10th elements of the original array, i.e. `b=np.array([0,2,4,6,8,9])`, how can I do it efficiently?

thanks

Comment: Indexing like this cannot be as efficient as a `slice`; but then you appear to be happy with 'another array', a copy as opposed to another way of looking at the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]]
```

Index `a` with a list or array representing the desired indices. (Not `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10`, because indexing starts from 0.) It's a bit confusing that the indices and the values are the same here, so have a different example:

```
>>> a = np.array([5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 0])
>>> a[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]]
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Note that this creates a copy, not a view. [Also, note that this might not generalize to multiple axes the way you expect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609734/numpy-ndarray-advanced-indexing)