# Crop part of np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Ihave a numpy array A like

```
A.shape
(512,270,1,20)
```

I dont want to use all the 20 layers in dimension 4. The new array should be like

```
Anew.shape
(512,270,1,2)
```

So I want to crop out 2 "slices" of the array A

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the python documentation](http://docs.python.org), the answer is:

```
start = 4 # Index where you want to start.
Anew = A[:,:,:,start:start+2]
```

Comment: thanks, and if I dont want to crop a conected invervall but eg. the first, the 5th, the 11th ... slice?

Comment: Read the excellent post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: got it, thank you. just use [-1,-..,-..] to get to the slice

Comment: See as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856133/irregular-slicing-copying-in-numpy-array for irregular slicing. You can thus do `Anew = A[:,:,:,[1,4,5]]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [a list or array of indices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) rather than slice notation in order to select an arbitrary sequence of indices in the final dimension:

```
x = np.zeros((512, 270, 1, 20))
y = x[..., [4, 10]] # the 5th and 11th indices in the final dimension
print(y.shape)
# (512,270,1,2)
```