# In Pytorch how to slice tensor across multiple dims with BoolTensor masks?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, advanced-indexing

I want to use BoolTensor indices to slice a multidimensional tensor in Pytorch. I expect for the indexed tensor, the parts where the indices are true are kept, while the parts where the indices are false are sliced out.

My code is like

```
import torch
a = torch.zeros((5, 50, 5, 50))

tr_indices = torch.zeros((50), dtype=torch.bool)
tr_indices[1:50:2] = 1
val_indices = ~tr_indices

print(a[:, tr_indices].shape)
print(a[:, tr_indices, :, val_indices].shape)
```

I expect `a[:, tr_indices, :, val_indices]` to be of shape `[5, 25, 5, 25]`, however it returns `[25, 5, 5]`. The result is

```
torch.Size([5, 25, 5, 50])
torch.Size([25, 5, 5])
```

I'm very confused. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch inherits its advanced indexing behaviour [from Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309460/boolean-masking-on-multiple-axes-with-numpy). Slicing twice like so should achieve your desired output:

```
a[:, tr_indices][..., val_indices]
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Seems I should learn more about numpy.